# Looking for more compact expression to generate matrix from vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a vector $v = \begin{pmatrix}
 v_1 \\
 v_2 \\
 \vdots \\
 v_n
\end{pmatrix}$, I need to generate a matrix $A$

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & v_1 + v_2 & \cdots & v_1 + v_n \\
v_2 + v_1 & 0 & & v_2 + v_n \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\
v_n + v_1 & v_n + v_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Currently, I describe this as

$$A = (v J_{1,n} + J_{n,1} v^{T}) \circ (J_{n,n} - I_n)$$

$J_{n,m}$ is an $n\times m$ matrix of ones and $\circ$ is the element-wise product.

Is there a more compact expression to generate $A$, potentially using some special product?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is always the option of writing something like $A_{ij}=v_i+v_j-2\delta_{ij}v_i$, or using your notation, $A=vJ_{1,n}+J_{n,1}v^T-2\operatorname{diag}v$.

Comment: Do you need just an expression to write somewhere or do you need an efficient method of computing this matrix?

Comment: For example in R, you can simply write `A <- outer(v, v, FUN="+")-2*diag(v)` which for any numeric vector `v` efficiently computes the matrix `A`

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks for the R code. I directly use the expression for calculation in Matlab. For my needs, this is sufficiently efficient. For documentation, I was just looking for an easier to understand expression.

Comment: @user10354138 I think index notation does the job. Thank you!

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks for the additional advice!

Comment: @user10354138 Would you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments, you have $A_{ij}=v_i+v_j-2\delta_{ij}v_i$ which is probably most obvious and naïve method of generating $A$.